# AJAX script change navigation on response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a simple search application in which I'm trying to use AJAX in order to navigate to different responses.

My problem is pretty straight forward and I'm sure that there is a simple solution to it but I am simply not able to find it.

I'm sending a new request this way:

```
xhrObj.open('post', 'search.do', false);
xhrObj.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhrObj.send('id=1');
```

I would like that, after this request call and the necessary business logic, the browser change the view to the new page specified in the back-end.
Instead of this, I'm receiving the page HTML code in the response but the navigation to this page never takes place.

I was under the impression that if the `async` parameter is set to `false` the flow would behave the way I was expecting.

How can I make my JS script to jump it's navigation to the a new page after an AJAX call. Please have in mind that I cannot use `location.href` to jump to the new page because this new page is a .JSP build on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have something similar what guthub has, you need HTML5 History API. Without HTML5 History API you can't manipulate URL (with help JS) without making any redirection.

Generally you could use hash in url (domain/#hash/blabla/bla) but it's not good also.

Comment: HTML5 is a buzzword. StackOverflow is a technical site, don't hesitate to use the correct words :) (History API).

Comment: and I'm sure you know that everyone, everywhere call it "HTML5 History API"

Comment: You can call it HTML5 History API or History API, it's the same. HTML5 alone is just not the same. It's a buzzword to designate everything new.

Comment: agreed together it looks like better. but not critical. Any developer understood what i meant, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should request for a url from the search.do then do this.

```
xhrObj.onreadystatechange=function()  {
  if (xhrObj.readyState==4 && xhrObj.status==200)
    {
    window.location=xhrObj.responseText;
    }
  }
```

hope this helps.